# Mode of configuration on Zigbee

Tags: pi-3b+, xbee

I connected one Zigbee with an overlay shield fixed on the RaspberryPi and one Zigbee attached to a vibration sensor. What mode should I configure on the Zigbee's?

Comment: I don't know anything about ZigBee, but it might be helpful to say what model modules you're using/add links and to describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Model of Zigbee:

https://store.ncd.io/product/900hp-s3b-long-range-wireless-mesh-xbee-pro-communications-module-with-external-antenna/

XPI overlay to attach the XBee to Pi:

https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-shield-for-raspberry-pi-2-3-with-outward-facing-i2c-and-xbee-port/
Aim - pi with Zigbee 1 read data (one-way communication) from the Zigbee 2 and 3 which is connected to the vibration sensors. In what mode should I configure the XBee's, API or AT? And if the Zigbee one is coordinator should the Zigbee be set as a router or endpoint?